# How to display Chinese/Korean/Japanese characters in Skype?

Tags: skype, chinese, japanese, korean

All the characters become squares in Skype.

Comment: This post helped me:
http://smallittips.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-solve-skype-japanese-characters.html It is for Japanese characters but it is probably the same problem for Chinese characters.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows OS? You need to install eastern language packs for it then. Basically this is not Skype's problem as it takes the language packs from the OS on your computer.

Take a look at [this Skype forum post](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=68333) for reference

To install the **language packs** you need your Windows installation cd. Go to Start> Control panel> Region and Language> Languages> Install Languages